# OIDC with Gluu 3.1.3 and OpenAM 6

Tags: openid, openam, openid-connect, gluu

**INSIGHT:**

1. **Gluu** supports *Bearer Authentication* for token introspection (accepts bearer token as an authentication header).
2. **OpenAM** supports *Basic Authentication* (accepts base64 encoded clientId:ClientSecret as a authentication header)

**QUESTION:**

How can I implement generic OpenID connect in Node js 10.9.0 which supports both Gluu and OpenAM?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to handle it in generic way, you will need to add some configuration to specify what type of authentication is expected(Basic/Bearer) and add switch-case/if-else for supporting both IDP's.